# How can I serialize a string resource?

Tags: android, serialization, localization, resources

I have a data class that extends Serializable. 
I have somme variables that are set using the objects data fields.

My data class looks like this

```
data class AvailablePollResponseModel(

    @field:JsonProperty("end_date")
    val endDate: String? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("question_count")
    val questionCount: Int? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("kind")
    val kind: Int? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("id")
    val id: Int? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("title")
    val title: String? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("required_questions_count")
    val requiredQuestionsCount: Int? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("status")
    val status: Int? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("start_date")
    val startDate: String? = null

) : BaseRecyclableObject, Serializable {
    val resources: Resources = Resources.getSystem()
    override val objTitle: String = title ?: resources.getString(R.string.UNKNOWN_STORE_NAME)
    override val objSubtitle: String = endDate?.let { resources.getString(R.string.AVAILABLE_UNTIL, DateHandler.formatReadableYearly(it)) } 
  ?: resources.getString(R.string.NO_END_DATE)
}
```

When i run the app I get the following error message

```
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of`com.workshop.collect.networking.responsemodels.AvailablePollResponseModel`,
> problem: String resource ID #0x7f0d0009  at [Source:
> (String)"[{"id":880,"start_date":"2018-05-14T10:52:02.393194Z","end_date":null,"user":{"first_name":"Joel","last_name":"Brostrom","full_name":"Joel
> Brostrom","pk":3,"id":3},"module_object":[],"collected_polls":[],"available_polls":[{"id":33,"title":"Run
> for
> life","kind":2,"status":0,"start_date":"2018-04-07T22:00:00Z","end_date":"2018-06-11T22:00:00Z","question_count":4,"required_questions_count":4},{"id":34,"title":"Store
> layout
> report","kind":0,"status":0,"start_date":"2018-04-07T22:00:00Z","end_date":"[truncated
> 278 chars]; line: 1, column: 393] (through reference chain:
> java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.workshop.collect.networking.responsemodels.CheckInResponseModel["available_polls"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

How can i localize my strings if I cant serialize them?

Comment: If I hard code the strings it runs but I need to localize the strings for this project.

Edit: The code is written in kotlin.

Comment: use Parcelable, Serializable is not supported with Kotlin its used by him internally.

Comment: Is it really necessary? I have about 15 data object that would need to be converted to parseable.
The boiler plate code itself is reason enough to make me cringe.

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Just use implement Parceable and after that define your String like this:

```
  @SerializedName("location_name")
@Expose
private String locationName;
@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
private Double latitude;
@SerializedName("city")
@Expose
private String city;
@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
private Double longitude;
@SerializedName("state")
@Expose
private String state;
```